# Visual Studio html tag formatting

Tags: html, visual-studio, formatting

For example, I have the following tag which its content is short

```
<div>It is short</div>
```

But after formatting, Visual Web Developer give me

```
<div>
    It is short</div>
```

which is ugly.

What I want is

```
<div>
    It is short
</div>
```

or keep the original input

```
<div>It is short</div>
```

How to set my required format in Options->Text Editor->HTML->Formatting->Tag Specific Options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS 2010, after following the path you specified, you would click to expand the Default Settings and then under both "Client tag supports contents" and "Sever tag supports contents" change the "Line breaks:" entry to be either "Before and After" which would give you

```
<div>It is short</div>
```

or "Before opening, within, and after closing" which would give you

```
<div>
    It is short
</div>
```